# Possible to inject dynamic code using PostSharp AOP

Tags: c#, attributes, aop, postsharp

Assuming I create a custom PS attribute `InjectCodeAttribute` which I apply to a class or class member, would it be possible to tell PostSharp to replace the attribute with dynamic C# code provided as a string.

For example, can I turn this:

`[InjectCodeAttribute]
public class MyClass`

into this:

`[DependencyProperty, Obfuscation(Feature = "renaming", Exclude = true, StripAfterObfuscation = true)]
public class MyClass`

by providing this string `[DependencyProperty, Obfuscation(Feature = "renaming", Exclude = true, StripAfterObfuscation = true)]` to the `InjectCodeAttribute` attribute?

Note: I am aware of the Custom Attributes functionality provided by PostSharp http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-introduction and that I could create an attribute that injects the example attribute, but I just want to know if it's possible to inject any code (even invalid code that maybe throws an exception/error during compilation) I provide as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no for the described use case. PostSharp runs *after* the C# compilation has already completed and processes the binary assembly. At this point it's already too late to add a string input for C# compiler.